# What's simpliest way to fill a multidimentional array? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, fill

I have the following:

```
$toys[1]['brand']= "";
$toys[2]['brand']= "";
$toys[3]['brand']= "";
$toys[4]['brand']= "";
// and so on..
```

I wanted to fill all the brands key with "blah"...

It would be nice if there was a:

```
$toys[*]['branding'] = 'blah';
```

with `*` meaning ALL. But unfortunately that's not available.

The next simplest way I can think of is a `foreach()` loop

but was just wondering if there's a function I may not be aware of that's kinda like `array_fill` but for multi-dimentional? Or at least if there's a better technique?

Comment: thanks to all who took time to reply on this one.. well it seems a simple foreach would do just fine instead of having to do a whole bunch of function and walkin and stuff. hehe thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Leave specific functions out. They cost more than a foreach loop and they probably contains the foreach loop as well.

Just go with something like:

```
foreach ($toys as &$a) $a['brand'] = '';
```

Isn't that easy and readable?

Comment: @Aiias, yeah forgot it, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at php's [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). You can apply a general function on every element in an array.

Try this:

```
function initialize_brand(&$value, $key) {
  $value['brand'] = '';
}

array_walk($toys, 'initialize_brand');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$toys[1]['brand']= "A";
$toys[2]['brand']= "V";
$toys[3]['brand']= "asas";
$toys[4]['brand']= "dfdf";
$toys[4]['otherkey']= "dfdf";

function change_branding(&$item, $key)
{
    if($key == 'brand') $item = '';
}
echo '<pre>';

array_walk_recursive($toys, 'change_branding');
print_r($toys);
?> 

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [brand] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [brand] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [brand] => 
            [otherkey] => dfdf
        )

)
```